# Dell G3 15 laptop display and audio static

Tags: memory, display, cpu, motherboard, dell-g3

I have a 2020 model Dell G3 15 gaming laptop. Yesterday, during a Signal call, the laptop display suddenly distorted, and a loud static came from the audio output. I held down the power button to restart, and the problem seemed to disappear.

It has since gotten worse. Every time it boots up, the exact same problem occurs within a couple minutes. It is not even enough time to try and open Device Manager and try disabling audio and display devices and/or update drivers.

I have done some tests with it to try and narrow down the problem, here are my observations:

- it occurs regardless of whether it is plugged in or using battery power
- if there is a monitor connected to the HDMI port, whatever is displayed on that seems to freeze (there is no distortion). However, the laptop display itself always goes into almost a snowstorm
- as mentioned, static noise comes from the speaker
- when this occurs, there is no response from the keyboard or mouse, my keyboard does not even light up
- I have opened it up and found no signs of burnt-out components

Some other things to note:

- being in a hot climate, the CPU temps have spiked over 90 degrees Celsius recently
- a Windows update occurred the other day

Specs:

- Windows 11 Pro
- Intel Core i5 10th Gen CPU
  (I can provide other specs if requested - it is harder to find them now that I can't access the system properties)

Is this likely to be a dying motherboard? Is it worth it to try and narrow down the problem any further, for instance, checking for faulty RAM?

Comment: If it is running Windows 11, it is not that old. Run the Dell Driver Updater and also run Memtest86.exe (several passes) to see if that helps.  If not, get it serviced.

Comment: @John I will run Memtest, but I don't think running the Dell Driver Updater will be possible since as I mentioned it basically crashes almost as soon as it boots up.

Comment: I was not sure.  See what memtest tells you,  and also get it serviced to see if a repair shop can help.

Comment: @John after a call to a repair shop, it seems that the motherboard is likely dead, and it's very hard to find a replacement.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I cannot offer much more.

Comment: Before discarding, repairing or replacing, try running from an alternative OS on USB, such as Windows PE or RE, or Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started). If that works, the issue is OS, drivers SSD/HDD, etc., *not* the motherboard.